# How can I model coilled support wires that look like metal springs?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm trying to model the coilled support wires around a sphere that look like metal springs.

[image]

I've been trying to create a curve to use a guide for a spring model, but haven't had success. I find it tough to get my curves the right distance off the sphere; it's also tough to get the right curvature.

[image]

Here's another example of my problem; I can't figure out how to get good curve placement such that it sits nicely on the surface of my sphere.

[image]

Is there a better workflow that I could use to model this?

Comment: You can draw with grease pencil on the mesh and convert it to curves

Comment: @brasshat I'm not asking about how to model a spring; my problem is creating the guide curve

Comment: Honestly, I think hand-placing the curve is your best option.  Just keep adjusting your view and viewing from different directions and tweaking until it looks good.  I usually tackle making curves like this by getting the basic shape first with a couple control points, then keep subdividing the curve and tweaking as I go along.

Comment: @Denis Your suggestion here is easy and even more accurate. You should post this as answer (IMHO).

Comment: The best way is still to place it by hand, because only like that you will get the imperfections and gaps. If it's too perfect it will look artificial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In complement to the answer given by [Duarte Farrajota Ramos](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/19307/duarte-farrajota-ramos) you can use a shrinkwrap modifier on the curve.

That can allow you to set the curves around the sphere the way you want *and* keeping a constant offset from the sphere.

[image]

[image]

In order to make it work well, give a subsurf to the sphere, because of the *"nearest surface point"* option in the *shrinkwrap* modifier.

**If** you do that before curving the spiral, once your placement is good :

- Add more resolution to the curve (in the curve panel *"preview U"*)
- Convert the curve in a mesh <kbd>Alt + C</kbd> then *"mesh from curve/..."*
- Then come back to a curve : <kbd>Alt + C</kbd> and *"curve from mesh"* in order to curve the spiral.

Answer (score 10):

Go to *File > User Preferences > Addons* and search for *Add Curve: Extra Objects* and activate this addon

In the 3D view add a new curve object from the *Spiral* type. Adjust its settings as desired.

Add a new curve circle with a radius similar to the sphere.

Now to the spiral curve apply an *Array* modifier fit to a curve using the circle as length definition.

Next add a curve modifier to it using again the circle as deformation curve.

[image: Create a spring spiral]

You can now freely adjust the bezier curve circle as desired to match desired length and radius. Set it's handles to *Free* and then subdivide it to make shorter segments.

[image: Adjust spring Spiral]

**EDIT**

The trick here is using a bezier circle as deformation in the *Curve* modifier, since it will guarantee a perfect fit around the sphere as long as the body is truly spherical. You can then rotate **both objects at the same time** (curve circle and spring-like spiral) at will and it should always fit around the curve.

Comment: I think he already has the making the spiral part down (look at the 3rd screenshot), he is asking how to position the curve across a surface.

Comment: I think this method covers placement too. If the 'body' part of the 'creature' is a sphere the trick here is to use a bezier circle as deformation. That will yield a perfectly circular deformation which will guarantee a perfect fit around the sphere with any desired rotation, as shown in the second GIF

Comment: Yeah, I think before I try to manually place curve points, I'm going to try piecewise circle segments like in this.. not sure which'll end up doing the trick.