# Mirror multiple meshes with bezier curve

Tags: mesh, modifiers, mirror, bezier-curves

I am standing in front of a problem, hopefully somebody knows a solution to it.

I have a torus array and inside a bezier curve; I've added a curve modifier to the array to follow the bezier curve as should be seen in the picture. The curve is parent to the array.

Now I had to copy the array multiple times to get the needed length and now I have multiple meshes arranged around a bezier curve and the modifiers are applied.

I just copied the whole thing, curve and meshes and turned them 180 degrees on Z axis to put them on the other side just to realize that I somehow need to mirror it to fit correctly, but if I do it starts looking like rubbish

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is not helping for the curve nor is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> properly combining the meshes, I tried before and after applying the modifiers.

I hope I could make it clear, thanks for the attention.

The left one is the one I need to flip/mirror, it has 4 meshes and the said bezier curve.
[image: The left one is the one I need to flip/mirror, it has 4 meshes and the said bezier curve.]

Comment: This looks awfully similar to what you describe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57615/how-can-i-model-these-support-wires/57618#57618 . Also if you need an array to fit a curve there is a mode called *Fit Curve* specifically for that purpose, check here for more details https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/how-to-evenly-space-vertices-along-several-segments-bezier-curve/47366#47366. Don't apply modifiers, or convert to mesh unless specifically needed, keep modifiers around for as long as viable.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. :) In my eyes it looks a bit off topic though, since I am looking for a way to mirror this thing anyhow and to be honest I don't see how this could help me at this part, might be my own newbie blindness, but stil. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found solution to my own question xD
So here we go:
I just picked all 4 meshes and then pressed alt+C and then clicked on mesh from curve and done. That such simple things can stop one from progress for like a good hour straight... anyway, riddle solved, case closed.